# How to add differents values after each specific value into a string with php

Tags: php, string, loops

I want to add differents values into a string in  after a certain value.

For example :

```
$values = [ "<first><first>","<second><second>","<third><third>"];

$string = "<A1>
               <B1>...<B1>
                <C1>...<C1>
                 <D1>
                  <example><example>
                 <D1>
               <B2>...<B2>
                <C2>...<C2>
                 <D2>
                  <example><example>
                 <D2>
            </A1>
            <A2>
               <B1>...<B1>
                <C1>...<C1>
                 <D1>
                  <example><example>
                 <D1>
            </A2>"
```

And i want to add the values after the `<example><example>` . Final result will be like this :

```
$string = "<A1>
           <B1>...<B1>
            <C1>...<C1>
             <D1>
              <example><example>
              <first><first>
             <D1>
           <B2>...<B2>
            <C2>...<C2>
             <D2>
              <example><example>
              <second><second>
             <D2>
        </A1>
        <A2>
           <B1>...<B1>
            <C1>...<C1>
             <D1>
              <example><example>
              <third><third>
             <D1>
        </A2>"
```

Comment: loop through your values, find first occurance of `<example><example>`, append your value / replace with  `<example><example>` + value, repeat

Comment: how to find the first occurance of <example><example> with php?

Comment: you can use  `strpos` for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static solution:

```
$values = ["one","two","three"];
$index = 0;
$string = "<A1>
                   <B1><B1>
                    <C1><C1>
                     <D1>
                      <example></example>
                      {$values[0]}
                     <D1>
                   <B2><B2>
                    <C2><C2>
                     <D2>
                      <example></example>
                     {$values[1]}
                     <D2>
                </A1>
                <A2>
                   <B1><B1>
                    <C1><C1>
                     <D1>
                      <example></example>
                     {$values[2]}
                     <D1>
                </A2>";
echo $string;
```

Dynamic solution:

```
$values = ["one","two","three"];
$index = 0;
$string = "<A1>
                   <B1><B1>
                    <C1><C1>
                     <D1>
                      <example></example>
                     <D1>
                   <B2><B2>
                    <C2><C2>
                     <D2>
                      <example></example>
                     <D2>
                </A1>
                <A2>
                   <B1><B1>
                    <C1><C1>
                     <D1>
                      <example></example>
                     <D1>
                </A2>";
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    "/(?<=<\\/example>)/",
    function($match) use (&$index, $values) { return $values[$index++];},
    $string
);
echo $result;
```

Comment: not a good way, `$values` are most likely dynamic values (count might change), which requires a dynamic solution

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code her
```

```html
<?php


$find_placeholder_string = "<example><example>";
$values = array("<first><first>","<second><second>","<third><third>");

$str = "<A1>
           <B1>...<B1>
            <C1>...<C1>
             <D1>
              <example><example>
             <D1>
           <B2>...<B2>
            <C2>...<C2>
             <D2>
              <example><example>
             <D2>
        </A1>
        <A2>
           <B1>...<B1>
            <C1>...<C1>
             <D1>
              <example><example>
             <D1>
        </A2>";


  
$stripped = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str));

$offset = 0;

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($values); $i++)
{
 $value_string_count = strlen($values[$i]);
 $find_placeholder_count = strlen($find_placeholder_string);
 
 $position = strpos($stripped, $find_placeholder_string, $offset);
 $stripped = substr_replace($stripped, $values[$i], $position+$find_placeholder_count, 0);
 $offset = $position + $find_placeholder_count + $value_string_count;
}
echo $stripped;


?>
```

e